# BITCOIN : wallet.dat corrupt, salvage failed

Tags: bitcoin

trying to recover an older wallet, Get the error message :

wallet.dat corrupt, salvage failed

No clue what it means or how I can solve it. Any advice is appreciated.

regards
Adrian

Comment: It means you lost the coins.

Comment: More details! What application do you use? Which OS? What kind of drive (SSD, HDD).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the client with the `-salvagewallet` command-line option which moves any existing wallet.dat to wallet.[timestamp].dat and then attempts to salvage public/private keys and master encryption keys (if the wallet is encrypted) into a new wallet.dat. Once you have your keys in place you can import them into a fresh copy of bitcoin and recover your balance.

Comment: Thanks, will try it at once. It seems to me that it is an old 0.3.1 problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get SpinRite ( https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm ) and run on your computer. 
Now there is no guarantees, but perhaps you luck out!

Also I assume you are talking about PC and you are using hard drive and not SSD.

Comment: Try to recover my wallet, Xp, hybrid drive

Answer (score -1):

Try this python script https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet

Dump the wallet with pywallet to extract the private keys:

python pywallet.py –dumpwallet -datadir="yourpath" > wallet.text --passphrase= PASSPHRASE

or this other one

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1404609.0